# How to work out Ib without Rb

Tags: transistors

Doing some practice questions for exam and came across this.

[image: the question]

I have done circuits like this but they have always had a Vcc and Rb on the base side. Thus I have no idea what equations to use and google is not being my friend today.

so yeh if anyone can point me in the direction of the equations to use for this circuit ill be very happy

Comment: All you need is LKV.

Comment: Do you know the \$\beta\$? Or \$I_c\$ Or \$V_c\$? It looks like you are not giving all of the information here. Generally \$I_e = I_b + I_c\$.

Comment: Ah yeh sorry forgot to mention the only details i was given is that  β= 50 and i have to find out IE, IB, IC and VC

Comment: Then it is easy. You can calculate \$I_e\$ easily. Then, using \$\beta\$ you can write the equation above in terms of one variable only.

Comment: ah okay but im not sure what the equations will be as im used to using stuff like this:
![Ic] (http://puu.sh/lw3xW/ea22338f39.png)
![Ib] (http://puu.sh/lw3DK/703118e214.png)

Comment: pics not appearing for some reason

Comment: You really shouldn't be using equation you are "used to". You should understand them, and use the ones matching your problem and modify/derive accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Hints

If any one of these steps makes you scratch your head then ask

1. What is the voltage at the emitter (broadly speaking)
2. Knowing Ve, what is current through 10k resistor
3. Knowing hFe or beta, what is current thru collector
4. What is voltage at collector

These are fairly straightforward but take your time.